# How to use `--no-edit` flag in a `git commit --amend` process inside magit?

Tags: magit, git

If I am using the terminal, after staging some changes, I can do:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

This will insert the staged changes on the previous commit. The editor to edit the message was **not open** to do it.

If I try the same on Magit, I can stage (s), commit (c), and amend (a). At this point, there is a window to edit the previous commit message.

Of course, I can simply press `C-c C-c` to finish the process without changing anything. It would have the same effect as using the `--no-edit` flag.

But, is there a way to use the `--no-edit` flag in Magit so that this edition window is not even necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly what [`c e` (“extend”)](https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#index-magit_002dcommit_002dextend) does.

And conversely, to change the commit message without amending the commit with the staged changes, there's [`c w` (“reword”)](https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#index-magit_002dcommit_002dreword).